# Visual Studio Code not showing console logs

Tags: logging, console, visual-studio-code

For example, in this method, I use console.log() to log to console for debugging purposes

```
_onSearchTextChanged = (event) => {
    console.log('_onSearchTextChanged');
    ...
};
```

But Visual Studio Code does not show anyting in console

[image]

Answer (score 23):

If you are using the debug mode in visual studio code,  you can add the option:

```
{
 "outputCapture": "std"
}
```

That will redirect your logs inside the debug console.

EDIT : as mentioned by Luigi04 in the comment section, this setting need to be put inside the launch.json

Comment: where should I put this setting?

Comment: In your launch.json file located in a .vscode folder in your workspace (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging)

Answer (score 6):

Inside `launch.json` (open it using <kbd>F1</kbd>), under `configurations`, add the `outputCapture` property (if not already exists) with either `std` or `console`, as follows :

```
{
  ...
  "configurations": [
    {
      ...
      "outputCapture": "std", // or "console" 
    }
  ]
}
```

as for `"std"`, this is what the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging) has to say:

> `outputCapture` - if set to std, output from the process stdout/stderr
> will be shown in the Debug Console, instead of listening to output
> over the debug port. This is useful for programs or log libraries that
> write directly to the stdout/stderr streams instead of using `console.*`
> APIs.

Also note that using `std` will show you full errors (as for VSCode 1.49.0). For example, create a js file containing an error:

```
console.log(a) // error: a is undefined
```

Using `std`:

```
c: \Users\path\to\file.js: 1
console.log(a) // error: a is undefined
    ^

ReferenceError: a is not defined
at Object.<anonymous>(c: \Users\path\to\file.js: 1: 13)
at Module._compile(internal / modules / cjs / loader.js: 1158: 30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js(internal / modules / cjs / loader.js: 1178: 10)
at Module.load(internal / modules / cjs / loader.js: 1002: 32)
at Function.Module._load(internal / modules / cjs / loader.js: 901: 14)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint[as runMain](internal / modules / run_main.js: 74: 12)
at internal / main / run_main_module.js: 18: 47
```

Using `console`:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined
```

so in my opinion, `std` is somewhat better.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I searched a text in the search bar long ago and searched text never got removed from the search bar. The search bar is so easy to miss, although it shown the text 0/173 signifying 0 lines matched out of 173 printed, but I couldn't figure out why DEBUG CONSOLE was completely empty. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

In Latest version of ***VSCode(1.83.1)*** the property name is changed. You have to instead use the below property

> "console": "internalConsole"

Sample launch.json

```
{"version":"0.2.0","configurations":[{"type":"node","request":"launch","name":"Launch Program","skipFiles":["<node_internals>/**"],"program":"${workspaceFolder}/src/app/pages/auth/auth.component.ts","outFiles":["${workspaceFolder}/**/*.js"],"console":"internalConsole"}]}
```

Comment: In Vscode 1.84.1, if you will try to put "console" in the configurations element in launch.json, you will get an error: "Property console is not allowed". Please remove this answer or explain it better.

Comment: @Rualark thanks for pointing that out, added a sample launch.json file for reference.

Answer (score -2):

If you are running & testing your code in the browser the press 'F12' (for google chrome) to see the logs in the browser.
If you are running in the debug mode, In Visual Studio Code then only logs will be displayed.In the menu bar there is Debug option to run in debug mode or u can find complete reference [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_debug-menu)

Comment: This is not an answer to the question