# Problem returning output on Visual Studio Code for Javascript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, output

I recently started learning Javascript and want to use VS code. So far I have console.log('hello world'), but there is no return on output. Instead, running the code returns terminal data.

Thanks y'all

Comment: How do you run the code?

Comment: you running in browser or in node with console? what is the expected behavior

Comment: I am running the code within the program. Although, I'm not sure if I should be running it on a browser.

Comment: `console.log` is like `print(f)` in other languages. its outputting something not returning it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm wondering if it has to do with updating Node.js.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Code not showing console logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45667351/visual-studio-code-not-showing-console-logs)

Answer (score 0):

press f12 and you'll see the chrome console

Comment: Hi, I want to see the code output within VScode. Although output shows nothing...